# Writing an event based SignalR Notification Service using DBContext ChangeTracker - separation of concerns

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-signalr

I have a controller that modifies appointments in a calendar. I want to use my SignalR hub to notify users à la "User X changed {appointmentTitle}: List: {Property} {OriginalValue} {NewValue}"

I'm a beginner in C# (Syntax-wise it's ok, but OOP concepts are new); I'm trying to use events to achieve the above.
Below are the handlers and arguments, an extract from the controller and a summary of my questions.

Code is abbreviated!

### EventArgs

```
    public class AppointmentChangeEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public EntityState AppointmentState = EntityState.Unchanged;
        public EntityEntry Entity = null;
        public ScheduleData Appointment = null;
    }
```

### EventHandler

```
    // maybe this could be just one, and let the consumer decide based on EntityState?
    public EventHandler<AppointmentChangeEventArgs> AppointmentChanged;
    public EventHandler<AppointmentChangeEventArgs> AppointmentAdded;
    public EventHandler<AppointmentChangeEventArgs> AppointmentRemoved;

    protected virtual void OnAppointment(AppointmentChangeEventArgs appointmentChangeEventArgs)
    {
        switch (appointmentChangeEventArgs.AppointmentState)
        {
            case EntityState.Added:
                AppointmentAdded?.Invoke(this, appointmentChangeEventArgs);
                break;
            case EntityState.Deleted:
                AppointmentRemoved?.Invoke(this, appointmentChangeEventArgs);
                break;
            case EntityState.Modified:
                AppointmentChanged?.Invoke(this, appointmentChangeEventArgs);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

### Controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Batch([FromBody] ScheduleEditParameters param)
    switch (param.Action) {
        case "insert":
             await _dbContext.Appointments.AddAsync(appointment);
             break;
        case "update":
             // .. get Appointment from DB
             appointment.Subject = value.Subject;
             appointment.StartTime = value.StartTime;
             // ...
        case "remove": 
             // .. get Appointment from DB
             _dbContext.Appointments.Remove(appointment);
    }
    var modifiedEntries = _dbContext.ChangeTracker
            .Entries()
            .Where(x => x.State != EntityState.Unchanged && x.State != EntityState.Detached)
            .Select(x => new AppointmentChangeEventArgs() { Entity  = (EntityEntry) x.Entity, AppointmentState = x.State, Appointment = appointment })
            .ToList();

        if (modifiedEntries.Any())
        {
            var notificationService = new NotificationService(signalRHub, notificationLogger);
            AppointmentAdded += notificationService.OnAppointmentChanged;
            AppointmentChanged += notificationService.OnAppointmentChanged;
            AppointmentRemoved += notificationService.OnAppointmentChanged;
        }
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

### Questions

- Is it ok to use EntityEntry and EntityState in event arguments?
- for each modified Entry, I can obtain `_dbContext.Entry(modifiedEntry).Properties.Where(x => x.IsModified).ToList();` - but does this belong in the NotificationService class? In order to do that, I'd also need to pass the DbContext over to NotificationService.
- Might there be a simpler way to achieve this? Adding and Removing handlers are easy ("User X has added|removed ... appointment {Title}"), but in order to figure out the exact changes I'll have to look at the modified properties.

I'd be grateful if you could provide an insight into how you would structure & handle this task. Thank you.

Comment: Just wondering: Where exactly does SignalR come into play here?

Comment: You got me, @poke: SignalR is part of the NotificationService, which I have omitted for the question. It obtains a HubContext and sends messages out to the user.
The question is more about on how and where exactly these messages should be constructed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start off, I would generally recommend you *not* to use events here. Events are something that may sound very useful but due to the way they work (synchronously), they aren’t really the best way to achieve this in a web context, especially in a primarily asynchronous framework like ASP.NET Core.

Instead, I would recommend you to simply declare your own type, e.g. `IAppointmentChangeHandler` like this:

```
public interface IAppointmentChangeHandler
{
    Task AddAppointment(ScheduleData appointment);
    Task UpdateAppointment(ScheduleData appointment);
    Task RemoveAppointment(ScheduleData appointment);
}
```

Your `NotificationService` can just *implement* that interface to be able to handle those events (obviously just send whatever you need to send there):

```
public class NotificationService : IAppointmentChangeHandler
{
    private readonly IHubContext _hubContext;

    public NotificationService(IHubContext hubContext)
    {
        _hubContext = hubContext;
    }

    public AddAppointment(ScheduleData appointment)
    {
        await _hubContext.Clients.InvokeAsync("AddAppointment", appointment);
    }

    public UpdateAppointment(ScheduleData appointment)
    {
        await _hubContext.Clients.InvokeAsync("UpdateAppointment", appointment);
    }

    public RemoveAppointment(ScheduleData appointment)
    {
        await _hubContext.Clients.InvokeAsync("RemoveAppointment", appointment);
    }
}
```

And inside of your controller, you just inject that `IAppointmentChangeHandler` then and call the actual method on it. That way you have both the controller and the notification service completely decoupled: The controller does not need to *construct* the type first and you also do not need to subscribe to some events (which you would also have to unsubscribe from at some point again btw). And you can leave the instantiation completely to the DI container.

---

To answer your individual questions:

> Is it ok to use EntityEntry and EntityState in event arguments?

I would avoid using it in a context outside of your database. Both are an implementation detail of your database setup, since you are using Entity Framework here. Not only would this couple your event handlers strongly with Entity Framework (meaning that everyone that wanted to be an event handler would need to reference EF even if they didn’t do anything with it), you are also leaking possibly internal state that may change later (you don’t *own* the `EntityEntry` so who knows what EF does with it afterwards).

> for each modified Entry, I can obtain `_dbContext.Entry(modifiedEntry).Properties.Where(x => x.IsModified).ToList();`

If you look at your code, you are first calling `Add`, `Update` or `Remove` on your database set; and then you are using some logic to look at some *internal* EF stuff to figure out the exact same thing really. You could make this a lot less complex if you constructed the `AppointmentChangeEventArgs` within those three `switch` cases directly.

> but does this belong in the NotificationService class? In order to do that, I'd also need to pass the DbContext over to NotificationService.

Does a notification service have anything to do with a database? I would say no; unless you are persisting those notifications into the database. When I think about a notification service, then I expect to be able to call something on it to actively trigger a notification, instead of having some logic within the service to figure out what notifications it could possibly trigger.

> Might there be a simpler way to achieve this? Adding and Removing handlers are easy ("User X has added|removed ... appointment {Title}"), but in order to figure out the exact changes I'll have to look at the modified properties.

Think about it in the simplest way first: Where do you update the values of the database entity? Within that `update` case. So at that point, where you are copying over values from the passed object, you can also just check which properties you are actually changing. And with that, you can record easily which properties you need to notify about.

Decouple this completely from EF and you will be a lot more flexible in the long run.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for taking the time to come up with this. I've got a lot to learn! I'll with this and will report back asap. Please bear with me a moment before I accept the answer.

Comment: Could you elaborate slightly on "And inside of your controller, you just inject that IAppointmentChangeHandler then and call the actual method on it." - should I register `<IAppointmentChangeHandler, NotificationService>()` as a scoped service to use it?

Comment: Yeah, exactly, you can register it like that and then inject the handler interface to use it. It doesn’t need to be scoped since you don’t use the database here though.

Comment: Sorry it took awhile to get back on the question. I've got one more question that I can't figure out with this approach. By not using Events I'm not able to add multiple subscribers easily - so say I'd like to add additional Notification services later, I'd have to go back and change the NotificationService, right? Is there a way to inject multiple instances or sth similar?

Comment: @ExternalUse You could register multiple types as `IAppointmentChangeHandler` and then instead of injecting just one handler, inject an `IEnumerable<IAppointmentChangeHandler>` to get a list of all registered handlers. And then just loop through those and call the method on each of them.

Comment: I guess I should have had that idea myself. Thanks for helping out a beginner!